# How to create only save only payment method enveloe request in docusign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I want to create envelope request which only save payment method for future payment.

Comment: @Inbar Gazit, can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature to do this. I tested and you cannot put 0 dollars (0.00) as the amount so the only option is to put 0.01 (1 cent) and that will allow user to enter their credit card or bank information. If the one cent is an issue - I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i see that we can send save payment method request through website using our account. so we can't do this through APIs.

Comment: FYI I have attached these screenshots.  https://ibb.co/FWJWXy3
https://ibb.co/JvPPr7r

Comment: can you please confirm?

Comment: I wasn't able to get an answer, sorry